# FPS drop when positioning the character

Tags: animation, 3d-view, vertices, optimization

My problem is as follows
(is a model ported from SFM to Blender)
Animation attempt unsuccessful
Solid Mode

When I create a frame with the rig or in positioning mode, The FPS ends up dropping to 3 or less than that. I've tried simplify, decimate and none of these worked.

I used several optimization tips that my friends recommended to me.

Frame Dropping.

Simplify.

Decimate.

As said before, it didn’t work

Comment: Please upload your file or give more infos and screenshots (how many vertices, which modifiers, PC specs, ....)

Comment: @joshsanfelici Here https://www.mediafire.com/file/38rp9w03zb55pn7/FILE.blend/file

Answer (score 1):

Your character has 145k vertices, which is quite high for a rigged prop.

One possible optimization, as many parts are "rigid" and don't need deformations, is to parent them directly to bones, without weights (select the mesh part, shift select the armature, go to pose mode, select the relevant bone and press Ctrl P - bone).

But I think you should make a copy of the character, replace its parts with an ultra simplified and decimated version, and use this proxy to animate, then use the original one for rendering.

To have an idea, in my computer your file runs at about 6 FPS, and if I don't want speed problems I stay under 30k vertices when animating.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, do I squeeze my bones and click with the CTRL P?

Yes, I'm trying to create a proxy, but I can't.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DE8JTqXL4YE&t=1098s

I'm using this video, but I can't find any way to play it in the current blender. Because I'm not advanced enough, can you help me with that too?

Comment: In 2.8 and above you can put the meshes and the armature in a collection, duplicate the collection in the outliner, turn off one of them. In the duplicate version put a decimate modifier on every mesh, set the amount of reduction, and apply it. When the character will have 10-20% of vertices (15-30.000) you should be good to go.

Comment: And then, if I want to animate, do I have to copy the frames from the proxy and paste in the original?

Comment: In the action editor (dopesheet), select the armature and choose the animation you've done from the dropdown menu (give a name to the animation for easy search).